# How to regenerate spec2006?

Tags: linux, cpu, benchmarking

My brothers compiled spec2006. I want to recompile it in my directory. But the iso file of spec2006 has not been found. I copied their compiled spec2006 to my directory, how should I recompile it?

When I execute uninstall.sh, it will appear

```
SPEC cpu2006 Tools Uninstaller

Top of cpu2006 tree is '/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006'
About to remove tools installation from "/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006".
Is this the desired behavior?
Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.
yes
Top of SPEC benchmark tree is '/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006'
Some important environment variables are missing!  Please source
/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006/shrc before running this program.
Removing previous tools installation
Error un-relocating Perl tools. The next installation will fix them up.
```

When I execute install.sh, it will appear

```
SPEC CPU2006 Installation

Top of the CPU2006 tree is '/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006'

There appears to be only one valid toolset:

linux-redhat62-ia32           For x86-based Linux systems with GLIBC 2.1.3+
tail: cannot open '+2' for reading: No such file or directory
==> /home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006/tools/bin/linux-redhat62-ia32/description <==
For x86-based Linux systems with GLIBC 2.1.3+
                              Built on RedHat 6.2 with gcc 2.95.3


Use this? (y/n)
y

Checking the integrity of your source tree...

/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006/tools/bin/linux-redhat62-ia32/specmd5sum: ATTENTION_DO_NOT_USE_THIS_KIT_FOR_ANYTHING_PUBLIC_FIELD_TEST_LICENSE_NOTICE: No such file or directory
/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006/tools/bin/linux-redhat62-ia32/specmd5sum: benchspec/CPU2006/465.tonto/src/slatershellvec.use: No such file or directory
/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006/tools/bin/linux-redhat62-ia32/specmd5sum: bin/specperldoc: No such file or directory
/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006/tools/bin/linux-redhat62-ia32/specmd5sum: WARNING: 3 of 10664 listed files could not be read

/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006/tools/bin/linux-redhat62-ia32/specmd5sum: WARNING: 4 of 10664 file sizes did NOT match

ATTENTION_DO_NOT_USE_THIS_KIT_FOR_ANYTHING_PUBLIC_FIELD_TEST_LICENSE_NOTICE: FAILED open or read
benchspec/CPU2006/465.tonto/src/slatershellvec.use: FAILED open or read
benchspec/CPU2006/483.xalancbmk/src/ElemNumber.cpp: FAILED size mismatch
benchspec/CPU2006/483.xalancbmk/src/FormatterToHTML.cpp: FAILED size mismatch
benchspec/CPU2006/483.xalancbmk/src/XalanDOMString.cpp: FAILED size mismatch
benchspec/CPU2006/483.xalancbmk/src/XalanExe.cpp: FAILED size mismatch
bin/specperldoc: FAILED open or read
Package integrity check failed.
Unpacking binary tools for linux-redhat62-ia32...
Checking the integrity of your binary tools...

Checksums are all okay.
Top of SPEC benchmark tree is '/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006'
Everything looks okay.  cd to /home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006,
source the shrc file and have at it!
```

What is shown above is *Everything looks okay*.

When I re-execute `install.sh`, the above message will appear again, and the error has not disappeared.

And I found that these files exist.

```
/home/yu/workspace/benchmarks/spec2006/tools/bin/linux-redhat62-ia32/specmd5sum

bin/specperldoc
```

What should I do? thank you all